# Why is table numbering not working with blogdown::html_page, but working with bookdown::html_document2?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, blogdown, huxtable

I have a report written in R Markdown that is supposed to use numbered sections, figures, and tables and cross-references to them: https://github.com/joshuaborn/NSFG/blob/master/reports/use-of-contraception-in-the-united-states-2017-2019.Rmd

When I render the file to output of `bookdown::html_document2` all the numbering and cross-references work fine. However, when I render the file to output `blogdown::html_page` for my blog, the sections and figures get numbered, but the tables don't. This also breaks all the cross-references to tables in the document.

The `blogdown::html_page` documentation says that it

> is a simple wrapper of `bookdown::html_document2()` with different default arguments, and more importantly, a special HTML template designed only for blogdown to render R Markdown to HTML pages that can be processed by Hugo.

So I think this might be an issue as simple as different arguments needing to be passed in to `blogdown::html_page`, but I looked through the documentation and the functions' source code and didn't find anything.

I have a workaround where I render the report to `bookdown::html_document2` with caching on, then delete the HTML file, and render it a second time to `blogdown::html_page` using the cache from the first render. This results in numbered tables with the HTML file in the appropriate format for Hugo. It would be nice to get to the bottom of this to make my build process have less overhead, though.

**Edit:** I created a minimally reproducible example: https://github.com/joshuaborn/minimal-example

Note that the `huxtable` tables are numbered and cross-references to it work in when `bookdown-article.Rmd` is rendered, but not when `blogdown-article.Rmd` is rendered.

Since this appears to be an issue with `huxtable` tables in particular, I've added a `huxtable` tag to this question.

A GitHub issue was created here: https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues/225

Comment: Maybe better to ask there: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues ?

Comment: @manro Good idea, but given my edit just now, I'll start with https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be fixed in a future version of `huxtable`. https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/commit/1a126bf876e4abb12e2949a063e67e53052ca660

In the mean time, including `options(huxtable.bookdown = TRUE)` fixes the issue.

Comment: Maybe add the version of `huxtable` that fixes the issue to the answer?

Comment: @Patrick It looks like the fix hasn't yet been included in any released version, though it is in the development working branch. I'll add a workaround to my self-answer.